# Error publishing SQLCLR C# Function using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, c#, sql-clr, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to (learn) publish a SQLCLR function using Visual Studio 2017. (It's a simple function that sends an email.)

As a reference I used this articles on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com) and [MSSQLTips](http://www.mssqltips.com):

[Create, Run, Debug and Deploy SQL CLR Function with Visual Studio 2013 Database Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/841439/Tips/841439/Create-Run-Debug-and-Deploy-SQL-CLR-Function-with)

[Send Email from SQL Server Express Using a CLR Stored Procedure](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1795/send-email-from-sql-server-express-using-a-clr-stored-procedure/)

On project properties->SQLCLR I've set:

`Permission level : UNSAFE`

And according to the article I've updated target databases:

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

And after I've got the error I've followed this advice on MSSQLTips article:

> If you get error messages when trying to compile the code you may need to alter the database using the following command and then try again to create the assembly and the stored procedure.

`ALTER DATABASE msdb SET trustworthy ON`

I've tried using two different target databases:

- SQL-Server 2017 LocalDB
- SQL-Server 2017 Express

I can build the project without errors, but when I publish the project I receive one error when it executes the next command:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [dbSysmac]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM 0x5F8A900003000000...
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```

> (47,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 10327, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'dbSysmac' failed because assembly 'dbSysmac' is not trusted. The assembly is trusted when either of the following is true: the assembly is signed with a certificate or an asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission, or the assembly is trusted using sp_add_trusted_assembly.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44086646

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've updated target databases:
>
> ```
>  sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
> ```

Just to be clear, "clr enabled", and `sp_configure` in general, are instance-level, not database-level configuration.

> I've followed this advice on MSSQLTips article

Yikes. Well, that article on MSSQLTips is more of a problem than the error that you are getting. It would be best if you forgot everything you saw in that article and never looked at it again. It is full of bad advice:

1. SQLCLR not required for [sending email in SQL Server Express](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/02/sending-mail-using-sql-server-express-edition/) (I have tested this and it does work). HOWEVER, it does *not* work in SQL Server Express LocalDB :-(
2. You should use `SqlString` instead of `String` for input parameter types (and for return types)
3. Deploying to `msdb`? Maybe it's just me, but I would never deploy code to `msdb` (and I would only add code to `master` if it is physically required, such as when marking a proc as either a start up proc or as a system proc).
4. `UNSAFE` permission set? Why? For email? The assembly should be `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`. Code (assemblies, logins, users, or anything else) shouldn't be given more permissions than necessary.
5. Setting `TRUSTWORTHY ON` for `msdb` is two problems in one:

   1. Setting `TRUSTWORTHY ON` is lazy. Sure, it's fine for doing proof-of-concepts / quick tests, but it is not a good long-term / production-level option. It's a huge security risk. Instead, [Module Signing](https://modulesigning.info/) should be used. Here is a guide I wrote for how to accomplish this, and do so within Visual Studio:
      [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: "CLR strict security" - Solution 1](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/)
   2. `TRUSTWORTHY` is already `ON` for `msdb`. At least it is `ON` by default.
6. The `@body` input parameter should be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, not `NVARCHAR(4000)`. This is, after all, HTML email (i.e. `myMessage.IsBodyHtml = True`)
7. No, absolutely do *not* store your plain-text email password in the .NET code. DLLs / Assemblies are not encrypted. *ALL* strings are stored *as-is* at the end of the EXE / DLL / Assembly. It takes almost no effort to display the contents of an assembly, and if you follow this advice, your SMTP server, login, and password will be stored for anyone to see. Either pass those in from a variable, or do a simple query to select from a table. You might even be able to get them from the Windows Registry.

What database are you actually publishing to? Assuming that you are publishing to another database that is not `msdb`, then you, at least simplistically, in this moment to move forward, need to set `TRUSTWORTHY ON` for the DB that you are publishing to. But again, enabling `TRUSTWORTHY` is just for testing (please see: [PLEASE, Please, please Stop Using Impersonation, TRUSTWORTHY, and Cross-DB Ownership Chaining](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/)).

Now, if you are executing the `ALTER DATABASE...` manually and then still get the error upon publishing, then most likely you have the "deploy database properties" option selected (in Visual Studio: go to "Project Properties" | "Debug" tab | "Deployment Options" area towards the bottom). `TRUSTWORTHY` is one of those database properties. So, when "deploy database properties" is checked, then every deployment will set the options to match what is defined in the project. And by default, `Trustworthy` is not enabled.

**Your options are:**

1. If you are deploying database properties:

   To enable `Trustworthy` in Visual Studio (for deployments): go to "Project Properties" | "Project Settings" tab | "Database Settings..." button | "Miscellaneous" tab. Check the box for "Trustworthy" and then click the "OK" button.
2. If you are not deploying database properties:

   Enable trustworthy in the database where you are deploying the assembly (enabling `TRUSTWORTHY` in `msdb` won't help)
3. Once you have this working correctly in development, handle security properly before pushing to production:

   [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: "CLR strict security" - Solution 1](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/)

For learning more about SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/). Be sure to check out the "Stairway to SQLCLR" link, which is a series I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central.

Comment: Let me check, it's my first vstudio db project and I'm a bit blind. BTW it is not `msdb` database, it's a new db. And second, I'm not sure to have file write permissions with my current windows account, at least on SQL Server Express, but I thought it could be easily done in Localdb

Comment: By now enabling `Trustworthy` in Project properties works well, but I want to go further, and links you have supplied is a good point to start. Thanks Solomon, is always a pleasure to read one of your detailed answers.

Comment: It works on Express edition but it don't on Localdb, still the same error.

Comment: @McNets LocalDB shouldn't be any different, at least not for this. If you are getting that same error, you need to make sure that you are setting the DB that the Assembly is being installed into to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`, and that you are not telling Visual Studio to overwrite that setting if it is deploying the DB properties.

Comment: According to your answer I've checked `Trustworthy` on Project properties, after the error, I've tried by manually add `ALTER DABASE MyDB SET TRUSTWORTHY ON` on the deploying script.

Comment: If fact, it is not a handicap, I'm just testing SQLCLR procedures, I'll follow your advice by reading your whole articles.

Comment: @McNets I hadn't thought of that, but look at the deployment script that it generates. Search for `TRUSTWORTHY` to see if it is there outside of the part you added. But yes, in general it is best to sign the assembly and have the asymmetric key / certificate in master, etc..

Comment: @McNets Also, make sure that your script is actually deploying the assembly to `MyDB` and not somewhere else ;-)

Comment: I've checked 'Always re-create database' in the publish dialog and now it worked fine. !!  I wonder if I could use a python script for this purpose, I mean, send an email.

Comment: I don't think you needed the "always recreate" option...be careful with that as it will drop whatever DB you are installing the assembly into every time you deploy. Also, is sending an email from LocalDB a requirement? If not, and you only need this in Express, then you don't need SQLCLR. The link I posted in item #1 (in the "bad advice" list from that other article) shows how to set this up in Express. I just got it working and was going to update my answer to state that. So far it is not working in LocalDB.